# How to calculate user inputted data from a for loop

Tags: ruby

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for num in numbers

  puts "insert q "
  qanswer1 = gets.chomp.to_i

  puts "insert 2nd q"
  qanswer2 = gets.chomp.to_i

end
```

This code will repeat the questions 5 times. How do I retrieve the user-inputted data?  I'm trying to calculate the total sum of all 10 responses and the index in which the sum of each pair was the highest.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to "calculate the sum of *each pair of* responses, the index of `num` for which the sum was greatest"? "and more" needs to be elaborated or struck. Please edit to provide a precise description of all information you wish to obtain. Do you want an array of the 10 responses or an array of the 5 sums, or neither, just the index of the greatest sum?

Comment: If `gets` returns `"25\n"`, `"25\n".to_i #=> 25`, just as `"29my dog has fleas".to_i #=> 29`, so `gets.chomp.to_i` can be simplified to `gets.to_i`,  which is how you normally see it written.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a solution as close as possible to yours while still producing the desired results :

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]

pairs = Array.new(numbers.size, [])

numbers.each do |number|
  pairs[number] = []

  puts "q 1:"
  pairs[number] << gets.to_i

  puts "q 2:"
  pairs[number] << gets.to_i
end
```

To get the pair with the max value:

```
max_value = pairs.max_by(&:sum)
```

To get the sum of all pairs:

```
sum_of_all_responses = pairs.flatten.sum
```

To get the index of the pair with the highest value:

```
pairs.index(max_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nbr_pairs = 5
```

```
def ask(str)
  print "#{str}: "
  gets.to_i
end

arr = nbr_pairs.times.map { [ask("insert q"), ask("insert 2nd q")] }
  #=> [[7, 3], [8, 6], [2, 9], [4, 6], [8, 3]]
```

*Sum of all 10 replies*

```
arr.flatten.sum
  #=> 56
```

*Index of largest sum of pairs*

```
nbr_pairs.times.max_by { |i| arr[i].sum }
  #=> 1 (8+6 = 14)
```

See [Integer#times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-times), [Array#flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten), [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) and [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store all the data, you could just do calculations on the fly.

First move the input request to a method which returns the pair of value n an array:

```
def ask
  puts "insert q "
  qanswer1 = gets.to_i
  puts "insert 2nd q"
  qanswer2 = gets.to_i
  [qanswer1, qanswer2]
end
```

Then set up variables

```
big_sum = 0
best_input = 0
best_input_q_number = nil
```

Finally loop as you did doing the math:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

for n in numbers
# (1..5).each do |n| # this is more Ruby-ish
  p qanswers = ask # p for debug
  qanswers_sum = qanswers.sum
  big_sum += qanswers_sum
  if qanswers_sum > best_input
    best_input = qanswers_sum # or qanswers if you want to keep the pairs
    best_input_q_number = n
  end
end
```